# Popover delay at bootstrap doesnt work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want the popover to hide after a while. I coded this -> [CODE](http://bootply.com/88002) work..
**JS**

```
$('#qoo').popover({
    placement : 'left',
    html : true,
    delay: { 
             show: 500, 
             hide: 100
    },
    content: function() {
    return $('#content-wrapper1').html();
}
```

});

**HTML**

```
<div class="span1 offset1">
     <a href="#" id="qoo" rel="popover" data-original-title="TITLEEEE" class="circle"> textttt</a>
     <div id="content-wrapper1" class="content-wrapper"> texttttttat</div> 
</div>
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Delay show / hide does not automatically show / hide the popover, it defines the delays **before** doing so! Also, [delay does not apply to manual trigger type](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers), so you must have a trigger, like `hover`. to get the delays to work.

```
$('#qoo').popover({
    placement : 'right',
    html : true,
    trigger : 'hover', //<--- you need a trigger other than manual
    delay: { 
       show: "500", 
       hide: "100"
    },
    content: function() {
        return $('#content-wrapper1').html();
    }
});
```

However, to achieve automatically hide for the popover, you can do the following by hooking into the `shown.bs.popover` event :

```
$('#qoo').on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#qoo').popover('hide');
    }, 1000);
});
```

The above hides the popover after 1000 ms, 1 second.

Comment: nice @davidkonrad ! i thought the reverse when i read the " delay does not apply to manual trigger type". However, in hover it works fine, but if i put a trigger: 'click' it doesn't work..

Comment: @yaylitzis, it works here with click as trigger (at least the delays)

Comment: See this: http://bootply.com/88054
I click the button, and after 100 ms it should be hided, right? (but it doesn't...)

Comment: @yaylitzis - No (!!) the delay works, but the popover is not hidden. And that has never been the intention. hide:100 just defines that _after_ click, the popover will hide after 100ms, eg delay the hide 100ms. To hide the popover automatically, after a certain time, you must use the timeout approach above. Show / hide only define the "effect", or delay, not the actions themselves!! See it logically - if it was true what you believe, then "show:500" should show the popover after 500ms - right? The bootstrap documentation is sometimes a bit vague or confusing.

Comment: thanks. Bummer though that the built in delay doesn't work when manually triggering the popover. Am I the only one who feels using setTimout isn't quite the same?

Comment: This will not remove the popover if the parent element is destroyed.

Comment: @sparkyShorts, so? in which version of bootstrap, and which setup? Feel free to produce a better answer.

Comment: @davidkonrad that's why I was here. I'm on 3.2 The issue that I am finding is the popover remains when the parent element is destroyed (as I previously stated). Our solutions are nearly identical. I ended up just finding the trigger that was removing the parent element and called popover('hide') as a work around. No disrespect intended. =]

Answer (score 2):

My solution: Popover opens only when the user hover over the link for a certain amount of time.

```
$('.popMonster').popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'manual',
    delay: { 
        show: 100, 
        hide: 0
    },
    container: $(this).attr('id'),
    placement: 'auto',
    content: function () {
        $return = '<div class="hover-hovercard"></div>';
    }
}).on("mouseenter", function () {

    var delay_ = (function(){
        var timer_ = 0;
        return function(callback, ms){
            clearTimeout (timer_);
            timer_ = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        };
    })();

    var self = $(this), url = '/myurl/action';

    delay(function(){
        // Get content via ajax:
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            if(data == 'Unauthorized.'){
                location.href = './';
            }else{
                self.attr('data-content', data);
                self.popover("show");
            }
        });
    }, 800 ); // time to wait before call ajax

    self.siblings(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
        self.popover('hide');
    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code, the problem in your code is that the tooltip does not seem be bound within the body, it is actually going outside the body, so if you will leave the margin for the element you would be able to get it working correctly. Take a look at this :

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/XBqMU/)

HTML :

```
<div class="span1 offset1" style="margin:100px">
     <a href="#" id="qoo" rel="popover" data-original-title="TITLEEEE" class="circle"> textttt</a>
     <div id="content-wrapper1" class="content-wrapper"> texttttttat</div> 
</div>
```

JS :

```
$('#qoo').popover({
    placement : 'right',
    html : true,
    delay: { 
             show: 500, 
             hide: 500
    },
    content: function() {
    return $('#content-wrapper1').html();
}                 

});
```

Comment: @yaylitzis have to referred the jsfiddle and tried editing the show and hide values, it is working !!