# How to delay popover till the data is ready

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to delay a pop over event to load content before it opens?

My code is the following:

```
$("[data-toggle='dcmntspopover']").popover({trigger : 'click',html : true}); 
$("[data-toggle='dcmntspopover']").on('shown.bs.popover', function() {     
    showDocuments(this); 
});
```

Comment: I used the following .....for popover showing plz help me...................................................................... ..                                                                               $("[data-toggle='dcmntspopover']").popover({trigger : 'click',html : true});
     $("[data-toggle='dcmntspopover']").on('shown.bs.popover', function()
     {
      showDocuments(this);
     });

Comment: you must edit your answer and place the code in it, instead of leave the code as a comment;

Comment: Are you loading the popover data from Javascript?

Comment: @induprakash.....yes..data is from javascript

Comment: from what I gather ..place the popover show call in success callback of your data fetch call. you can post some code to be specific.

Comment: Yes  damitj07 comment is valid.or else you can try 'delay' attribute.refer this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397636/popover-delay-at-bootstrap-doesnt-work"

Comment: You can also place show call in complete callback if it's ajax call.

Comment: cant you use document ready event?